# latitude longitude search in ALL state or county gis sites

Tags: latitude-longitude, search, county

I'm working in geography field now and
using local gis sites for different states and counties.

However, they all seem different, and it takes time to 
learn each new one as required.

For example, now I am using the Maine gis at 
http://mapserver.maine.gov/basemap/index.html.
I found the way to search by lat/long on the
last county gis I was on in colorado, after some
searching for it.  However, I cannot find such a
feature on the maine one yet, and it's starting to take
too much time.

Can anyone help me find the lat/long coords search function
on that site, or else refer me to a more global gis search site
that will provide property parcels, addresses, lat/long,
so that I won't have to learn each state or county gis site
individually?

I am new to gis so I am a bit naive about the whole thing.

Comment: openstreetmap.org will have some of this information, but I don't think it will have everything you require. Assuming you're looking for individual addresses, even census.gov blockgroup data won't be good enough.

Comment: Its certainly not available globally - most countries want to charge for data, and how its presented is at least regional (e.g. EU INSPIRE makes it somewhat common). Some countries don't even have the concept of parcel data. Perhaps you can constrain this to be only USA, but I'm not sure even that will be available.

Comment: There is no mandatory 'standard' for online GIS data; you're not going to find a 'GIS Google' anywhere! If you want to develop something you have to take into account the different web APIs. Esri has a standard metadata that would work with Esri built sites provided 1. The interface is exposed. 2. Metadata exists (and is correct). Different levels of enthusiasm toward searches definitely makes finding data more challenging... perhaps it would be best to contact them and ask - they might have a search that's only available internally or be able to point you to one.